# terraform relative path in locals

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

how do we capture relative path in terraform in main.tf. Here is the directory structure.

```
project-1
         |
        lambda_function
         |
        lambda_layer
         |
        terraform
                 |
                 dev 
                  main.tf
                  output.tf etc
```

Lambda deployment package use locals with data achieve in main.tf

```
data "archive_file" "run_functon" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = file("${path.module}/lambda_function/scripts/lambda_function.py")
  output_path = file("${path.module}/lambda_layer/layer.zip")
}
```

Error- path not found. Basically it should create layer.zip inside lambda_layer directory. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems like you already have the solution in your question since you already are using `path.module`. You just need to fix the path in your argument values to resolve to the file location.

Comment: Thanks. I blindly put path.module. What path does it return? Sorry new to terraform.

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/references.html#filesystem-and-workspace-info

Comment: so seems like path.root returns something like that, 'c:/users/project1/terraform/dev.'. have to change directory to one step above.

Comment: Add '/..' to the path you append to `module.root` (e.g. "${path.root}/../lambda_layer/layer.zip"). '../' is a general pattern, not Terraform specific,  that refers to the 'directory above' .